# Ways to implement auto voting feature on a content type?

Tags: 7, polls

I have a content type called "articles".  A user adds a new article and other users on the site can vote for the article.  I am using the Drupal default poll module.  In order for this to work, I have to do the below steps:

1. Create new poll.
2. Link submitted article to newly created poll.
3. Publish article to open it up for voting.

I am trying to eliminate step 1 and step 2.  In other words, the poll would immediately be registered into the newly submitted article.  Aside from writing my own custom module, is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) might be useful for what you are trying to accomplish.

> This module provides flexible voting widgets for nodes and comments.
>
> Administrators can add multiple widgets. By default, there are 8 widget types to choose from:
>
> - Thumbs up
> - Thumbs up / down
> - Number up / down
> - Fivestar
> - Emotion (this makes me mad, angry...)
> - Yes/no
> - Slider (Drupal 6 only)
> - Custom

Comment: To Elaborate on aerozeppelin's answer. You can use the Rate module to attach a voting widget to your content type. The rate module has a nice integration with views, so you can create a page view that pulls all of the articles for voting onto one page and allows user to vote.

Comment: Excellent!  This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, aerozeppelin and nicoz